# add a button at the bottom of a footer of UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
 @objc func hello(sender: UIButton!) {
print("Hello");

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection 
section: Int) -> UIView? {

guard section == 0 else { return nil }

let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(0,0,130,0))
let DoneBut: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(10, 3, 300, 44))
DoneBut.setTitle("become a captian?", for: [])
DoneBut.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
DoneBut.cornerRadius = 10
DoneBut.shadow = true
DoneBut.addTarget(self, action:#selector(hello(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
footerView.addSubview(DoneBut)
return footerView;

 }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
   estimatedHeightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
   return 50
}
```

I'm trying to make `DoneBut` at the bottom center of the footer but it's not happening!! this is what I see now

[image]

Comment: Add a container view and center your button within your containerView. The maths should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should do is to determine this after creating the button by telling what's the desired origin, it might be (Note that it is **Swift 4**):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    guard section == 0 else { return nil }

    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 44.0))
    let doneButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 130, height: 44.0))
    // here is what you should add:
    doneButton.center = footerView.center

    doneButton.setTitle("become a captian?", for: .normal)
    doneButton.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    doneButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    doneButton.shadow = true
    doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hello(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    footerView.addSubview(doneButton)

    return footerView
}
```

So, if you are unable to use Swift for, just to recap you should add:

```
doneButton.center = footerView.center
```

after declaring the button. By setting the button [center](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622627-center) to be the same as its container view (`footerView`) center, it should be exactly in the middle of it (x and y axis), thus you would get your desired appearance.

Comment: thanks. this helped to center the button but the button isn't at the bottom of the UITablevew. how can I do this?

Comment: @leo0019 try to add a background color to the `footerView` and see where is has been added.

Answer (score 2):

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return getfooterView()
}

func getfooterView() -> UIView
{
    let Header = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Double(self.tableView.frame.size.width), height: 45))
    Header.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#2AF8AC")
    let button = UIButton()
     button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Header.frame.size.width , height: Header.frame.size.height)
    button.backgroundColor = .clear
    button.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SubmitAction), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

    Header.addSubview(button)
    Header.bringSubviewToFront(button)
    return Header
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 45
}
```

[image]